# How to get nil from string.data(using: .utf8)

Tags: swift, string, xcode, utf-8, swift5

Is there any string that fails to construct "".data(using: .utf8) and returns nil?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/can-encoding-string-to-data-with-utf8-fail/22437)

Comment: I have seen that. It's not longer working in new swift versions.

Comment: @michalmichalek you can safely force unwrap the result. All Apple samples of JSON decoding they force unwrap the result of this method.

Comment: @michalmichalek https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/can-encoding-string-to-data-with-utf8-fail/22437/3), `string.data(using: .utf8)` is the same as `Data(string.utf8)`, which can't fail (for now, anyway. This is an implementation detail.).

Therefore, there is no string that you can use, to make `data(from: .utf8)` return nil.

`data(from:)` is declared to return an optional because you can pass in other encodings, which may not support the characters in the string. The method can't suddenly change its return type to non-optional just because you passed in `.utf8`, after all!